# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an area for admin functionality. I want my URLs to look like so:

admin/{controller}/{slug}.{id}/{action} *(i.e. admin/user/getoutofmylab.1/edit)*
admin/{controller}/{action} *(i.e. admin/user, this is just the index page of the user controller)*

When I browse from the root of my app to the user controller, I get admin/user. Links for the edit action of the user controller generate correctly. However, if I link to the index action from within any other action in that controller, the URL is generated as such: admin/user/{slug}.{id}, which, if clicked, generates a 404 not found error.

Here's my AdminAreaRegisration:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_Applications",
            "admin/{controller}/{slug}.{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = "" },
            new string[] { "Web.Portal.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );

        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Web.Portal.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
    }
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to link from an action in one controller, to an action in a seperate controller?

Comment: These are all in the same controller. It's just that when I'm within the "edit" action, for example, the link to the "index" action on the _Layout page generates with the slug, when it should just be /admin/user.

Comment: It seems using Html.RouteLink and specifying the action works rather than using Html.ActionLink: `@Html.RouteLink("List Applications", "Admin_Default", new { action = "Index" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using Html.RouteLink and specifying the action works rather than using Html.ActionLink: 
    @Html.RouteLink("List Applications", "Admin_Default", new { action = "Index" })